# how to create new list relate to the input list and input value in python

Tags: python-3.x

I just got a old lath machine from my grandparent, because some of moving parts is wear and have issue for buying new parts, so my idea is, if the the hand wheel need to turn quarter(few hundred steps, let we said 400 steps)  before tool bit is moving from forward to backward, so the logic is in following:
if f(n) > 0 and f(n+1) < 0 then step-motor is negative value for backward.
if f(n) < 0 and f(n+1) > 0 then step-motor is positive value for forward.
if f(n) < 0 and f(n+1) < 0 or f(n) > 0 and f(n+1) > 0 then step-motor is 0 for no-moving.
in the end create new list ex.[400, -400, 0, 0, 400]
program in following:

```
import ast

def data(getdata, w):
    l = ast.literal_eval(f"[{getdata}]")
    wear = ast.literal_eval(f"[{w}]")

    lx = [x for x,y,z in l]
#-----------------difference (n+1)-n---------------------
    x = lx
    xv = []
    for f in range(len(x)-1):
        bx = x[f+1] - x[f]  
        xv.append(bx)   
    print(xv)
#-------------something wrong in following-------------------   
    xwl = []# x-wear list
    for wx in  range(len(xv)-1):
        wrxs = xv[wx-1]# wear rate x secondary
        wrxp = xv[wx-1]# wear rate x primary
        if (wrxp > 0 and wrxs < 0):
            wdx = -wear#wear diraction in x-axis
        elif (wrxp < 0 and wrxs > 0):
            wdx = wear
        xwl.append(wdx)
    print(xwl)
#-------------something wrong in above-------------------

while True:
    getdata = input("coordinate in (x, y, z):")
    w = input("machenical wear in steps:")  #let we said 400 steps
    data(getdata, w)

#(0,0,0), (200,400,500), (-400,350,250), (110,-630,-125), (333,220,777)
```

the error code:

```
local variable 'wdx' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Is it possible that there is a situation were both `(wrxp > 0 and wrxs < 0)` and `(wrxp < 0 and wrxs > 0)` are `False`? If so, then `append(wdx)` will fail because `wdx` was never assigned (and thus referenced before assignment).

Comment: programming is my new habit, I still cannot understand where it goes wrong, it would be helpful if this problem can be solved. Because non centre lathing is quite dangerous for making crankshaft.